# HIVE Get Min 1 column and keep all the others column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am using Hive.
Suppose I have a column Log(userID, time, describe)
I want to select `userID`, `min(time)`, describe from Log group by userID.
Is There any way I can do that with Hive in 1 step? It's Seem really easy when I think about `mapreduce <key, value>` algorithm aspect, but I have so many files, and have another step too, so that lead to my problem.

Example:

```
(userID, time, describe) = {(1, 2, 2), (2, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 1)}
```

What I expect:

```
(userID, time, describe) = {(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done uning [CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression)  and  [Window function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics)  rank
.

Ie

```
    with result as
    (
        select userID, 
              time,
              describe ,
              rank() OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY time asc)  as rnk
        from Log
    )
    select userID,
       time, 
       describe
    from result where rnk =1
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work